# joomla smart search show all results

Tags: php, search, joomla

Is it possible to show all results in one page, of Joomla's component "Smart search"?

I'm using Joomla 3.x but at the bottom of the results page there is a standard pagination showing "Previous 1 2 3 4 Next". I want to show all the results on the first page, so there is no need for pagination.

I have already overridden the Smart Search but I'm struggling with this code:

```
    // Prepare the pagination string.  Results X - Y of Z
    $start  = (int) $this->pagination->get('limitstart') + 1;
    $total  = (int) $this->pagination->get('total');
    $limit  = (int) $this->pagination->get('limit') * $this->pagination->pagesTotal;
    $limit  = (int) ($limit > $total ? $total : $limit);
    $pages  = JText::sprintf('COM_FINDER_SEARCH_RESULTS_OF', $start, $limit, $total);
?>
    <br id="highlighter-start" />
    <ul class="search-results<?php echo $this->pageclass_sfx; ?>">
        <?php
        for ($i = 0, $n = count($this->results); $i < $n; $i++):
            $this->result   = &$this->results[$i];
            $layout         = $this->getLayoutFile($this->result->layout);
        ?>
        <?php echo $this->loadTemplate($layout); ?>
        <?php
        endfor;
        ?>
    </ul>
```

(template/html/com_finder/search/default_results.php)

It does calculate the total amount of results, so is it possible to just show that instead of the for loop?

Comment: What if you have 50,000 results?

Comment: I don't have 50.000 results.

Comment: But who knows . so just chnge he list length.

Comment: Easier said than done. I don't think I can define an absolute list length right? I can't seem to find why there is no `&show all` parameter, just as there is a `&limitstart` parameter. Do you mean I should change the list length in code, or is this also possible in the Joomla menu? I couldn't find it in the backend.

Comment: First of all there is a general list length parameter in global config. So my point about 50,000 results is that you just want a high number, you do not really want to show all no matter what, it would make you site unusable. So just change &limitstart to 1000 or something.

Comment: Also you might be better off on the joomla stackexchange site.